# What would be the translation for Her Royal Highness Princess Barbie?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I've looked at multiple translators but unfortunately they've mostly contradicted each other so I don't know if Her Regalis Celsitudinem Princeps Barbie is correct??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't know if Her Regalis Celsitudinem Princeps Barbie

Well, “Her” is obviously not Latin and the cases are a little wonky; however, I think that the most difficult part of the question is how to render the title “Highness” in Latin, and *celsitudo* appears to be the correct answer; or at least this title has been historically used for people that in English would be called “Highness” (e.g. by Calvin writing to Nikolaus Radziwill the Red).

Using *Sua* for “Her” and correcting the wrong accusative, we get:

**Sua Regalis Celsitudo Princeps Barbie**

I would, however, suggest a few possible changes:

- Instead of *Regalis* you could say *Regia*. Both forms (in combination with *Celsitudo*) are found in Neo-Latin writings. Both are completely acceptable, but I would personally prefer *regia*.
- Instead of *princeps*, you could use the explicitly female form *principissa*. With this obvious back-translation we leave all pretensions to Classical Latin behind, but Classical suggestions are usually something like *princeps femina, virgo regia, regis filia*, etc.; not simply saying *princeps* for a woman (although it can technically be parsed as a feminine adjective). However, we are translating a decidedly non-Roman style, so I would have no problem with a Neo-Latin term like *principissa*.
- You could Latinize “Barbie” as *Barbara* – this is obviously up to personal taste.

Thus my preferred form would be:

**Sua Regia Celsitudo Principissa Barbara**

Comment: Is the reflexive expected in this context in Latin? I've noticed modern languages with reflexive possessive pronouns seem to prefer to translate the phrase "his/her highness" to non-reflexive possessive pronouns in general, unless there's a specific grammatical context requiring it ("she picked up her highness from the ground").

Comment: @Agnes If you look on Google Books, you will find that both forms were in actual historical use, i.e. *Sua Celsitudo (Maiestas, etc.)* as well as *Eius Celsitudo*. I'm not sure what modern languages you have in mind, but I would in any event judge this from an inner-Latin point of view. So if the *princeps* in question is the subject, use *sua*, otherwise *eius*. Or don't you think *Eius Celsitudo, Serenissimus Princeps Austriae, veniet* sounds weird and prompts the question *cuius?* But admittedly, *Sua Celsitudo veniet* could be translated as "Its own Highness will come."